# Email Replies To SQL

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, html, email

When a customer fills out an HTML/C#/ASP.NET web form they are automatically emailed with a confirmation message. This works fine.

Instead of having to check an email account for customer replies, is there any way that their email replies can go straight to a SQL database table so that our management application can read in the replies/requests immediately? I have done some google searching and this seems not possible.

Common Scenario:

1. Customer fills out form
2. Customer submits form and receives email confirmation.
3. Customer replies to from email with questions
4. Replies would be saved in SQL table and read in by management tool.

If this is not possible we can just use email. Just making sure.

Comment: Once your email has been delivered to them and is in the scope of their email application, I don't think you have any recourse beyond having an actual application instead of a person monitor the email account and jam new emails into the database. If you control their email application, then that is a different story, but I am assuming that your emails go out into the world to various services outside of your control.

Comment: I don't think they want to record when the customer *receives* the email. They want to record the *replies*. They would have full access to the email account that receives the reply email. That should be perfectly doable (by someone that's better with C# than I).

Comment: My impression is that the customer is replying to automated emails which go to an account that is probably not regularly monitored, and they would like to not have to monitor that account. So, I tend to agree even though I had a different impression: as long as they can access the account then they can write an application to do whatever they want with the emails that have been received by that account.

Comment: No, SQL Server is not an email server. It can't receive emails. You'll need to write some code that will grab emails from the email server and load the data into the database.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments and I agree. It makes sense to just use email instead of within the application.